# How to update the content inside of Page object from Spring Data without changing the other properties

Tags: spring-boot, data-paging

after querying from the database using the given `getAll(Pageable pageable)` method from spring data jpa i become an Page object. What I am doing is modifing the content list inside of this Page object but I am getting stuck here is that I dont know how to set it back to the Page object because Page doesn't have setter method, something like `page.setContent(newContent)`, it has only getter.

Can anyone give me some hints how to set the new content to the Page object without changing the other current properties inside of it?

Comment: There is no way, you must construct new Page instance (`org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl`) based on Page obtained from `getAll` call. Question is why do you even need to modify the original page?

Comment: The same case as me.---
> Question is why do you even need to modify the original page?---
Repo method returns a collection of entities, but I what to pass to user thier representation. Suppose, I don't want to pass `user.password` or `user.email` for the users list request.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **PageImpl(List content, Pageable pageable, long total)** as example below :

```
//get paged data 
Page<Groups> groups = groupsRepository.
                    findPagedGroups(pageable, lowerCase(name), lowerCase(description));

// update list
List<Groups> groupsList = groups.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
for (Groups group : groupsList) {
   group.setSize(usersGroupsRepository.countActiveUsersGroupsForGroupId(group.getId()));
}

// return new PageImpl
return new PageImpl<>(groupsList, pageable, groups.getTotalElements());
```

Comment: Note: this example produces N+1 query

Answer (score 0):

Page's `map` method returns a new Page with the content of the current one mapped by the given converter function.

```
public Page<User> findAllMasked(Pageable pageable) {
    Page<User> users = repo.findAll(pageable);
    return users.map(user -> {
        user.setPassword("***");
        return user;
    });
}
```